# How long does Google Drive app folder live after factory reset

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I plan to use Google Drive app folder for the backup and multi-device sync for my Android App.  The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder#what_is_the_app_folder) says "Your App Folder is deleted if users uninstall your app from their Drive."  If the user lost her phone and whoever found it did a factory reset, I wonder how much time my user has to find another phone, install the app and restore the data before the app folder is deleted by Google.  If there's not enough time, I may choose to store the data in a regular folder.  The downside is that the user can tamper with the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user "uninstalling your app from **their Drive**" is not at all related to uninstalling your Android app. Google never deletes any information from your app folder upon uninstall or any time afterwards, but users can, at any point, delete the app folder associated with your app from their Google Drive.